# ¿Por qué tengo este error? arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " % 50 +1"

Tags: bash, shell, random

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(($RANDOM % 50 + 1))
```

Cuando ejecuto este código recibo el error:

> arithmetic expression: expecting primary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este error ocurre cuando ejecutas el script con sh en lugar de con Bash:

```
$ cat script.sh
echo $(($RANDOM % 50 + 1))
$ bash script.sh
37
$ sh script.sh
a: 1: a: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " % 50 + 1"
```

Por tanto, la solución es fácil: ejecuta con Bash. O simplemente ejecuta con `./script.sh`, pues el shebang `#!/bin/bash` ya está indicando qué intérprete usar.

¿Y por qué ocurre esto? Porque RANDOM es una extensión de Bash y en dash no significa nada. Así, `$RANDOM` es vacío y cuando le dices `echo $(($RANDOM % 50 + 1))` él lo que hace es `echo $(( % 50 + 1))`, lo cual no tiene sentido porque no hay nada a la izquierda del `%`.

Answer (score 2):

@fedorquí ya dijo como solucionarlo (usando otra shell), pero tu error me parece que es causado porque la shell `sh`, que en realidad es la sencilla `/usr/bin/dash`, no tiene la variable `$RANDOM`.

Entonces, cuando haces tu operación:

```
$ sh -c 'echo $(($RANDOM % 50 + 1))'
```

Te pide un número sobre el cual operar, pero `$RANDOM` no existe. Si en lugar de esa variable, ponemos otro valor:

```
$ sh -c 'echo $((50 % 50 + 1))'
1
```

Vemos que si funciona.

**Esto lo digo como conjetura sin leer el manual, y claramente carece de todo tipo rigor.**

Comment: exacto, el problema es que RANDOM es extensión de Bash. [Bash variables en GNU Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables).